# Script is suddenly unable to find a GameObject in the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Last night I was working on my game, and everything seemed to be working perfectly. I added a sprite to my Assets/Sprites folder, then my laptop died. When I plugged it in and turned it back on, the `GameObject.Find("Weapon Wheel")` line in my PlayerControls script was no longer able to find the weapon wheel object. To my knowledge, no changes to the scene or any scripts were made.

Even stranger, my CommandPattern script also has `GameObject.Find("Weapon Wheel")`, and is able to find it perfectly fine.

Has anyone experienced the Find function suddenly not working, and if so, found a solution for it?

EDIT: Deleting the player prefab then replacing it with a new one fixed the issue, but I still have no idea why this happened in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I dunno how ur game is architectured and a direct solution but you can try to create a Gameobject variable in the Playercontrol class and then drag the weapon wheel in the field in the unity overlay

Comment: That doesn't really address the problem though. The function was able to find the object perfectly fine before